# Switch with mdc-icon lateness

Tags: html, angular

I have the following code :

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="compare" >
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Compare </th>
  <!--<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let protocol"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></td>-->
  <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let experiment" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
    <button mdcIconButton [on]="true">
    <mdc-icon mdcIconOn #content onClick="onSelect(1, experiment)">radio_button_unchecked</mdc-icon>
    <mdc-icon onClick="onSelect(2, experiment)">radio_button_checked</mdc-icon>
  </button>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

which is working but sometimes it has delay and do not get it when I select a radio button, and this is a problem. Usually when I choose slowly, it gets it.

I wanted to know if there was another simple way to do a toggle switch like this one, without using mdc-icon because apparently it's a problem. I don't understand how to use ng-switch for exemple...

I tried this :

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="compare" >
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Compare </th>
  <!--<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let protocol"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></td>-->
  <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let experiment" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" >
        <button (click)='onSelect(1, experiment)'>Select</button>
        <button (click)='onSelect(2, experiment)'>Unselect</button>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

and it confirms the problem is coming from the mdc-icon, because it works quickly and gets my selections.
But obviously it's ugly and not switching.

Comment: What does "gets it" mean?

Comment: I meant the consol.log() appears, because I have one that is launched when the (click) is detected (so at the beginning of the function) and the other one when the precise part of the function is launched, so both appears when it works, the first one is just here to show that the problem doesn't come from the function, but from the mdc